# Incognito tab is not working properly

Tags: tabs

since recently i have problem using Incognito tab. Every time i try to type something on address bar the letters does not appearing. The cursor at the address bar(not from the mouse) is there few seconds and then is gone, it is invisible and that is happening from the very beginning after i open the INCOGNITO tab.
I am using Chromium browser downloaded from Ubuntu software.
So incognito tab is not working properly, does any one know why is that happening?

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using Windows 10 and Mozilla Firefox, and it only happens when in incognito. It would be nice to have a solution.

Comment: This is someone with the same issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1635837. The solution did not work for me (removing zulstore.json).